# Save training progress as an image in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I would like to save the final training result in `.png` or `.jpg` format. Without having to take a screenshot via function.

[image]

I've tried several ways but I can only save in `.fig` format.

The solutions I've tried are as follows:

- [savetrainingplot function](https://it.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/75604-save-training-progress-as-an-image-for-publication-purpose)
- [screencapture](https://it.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/831163-save-finalized-training-progress-plots-using-outputfcn)
- [saveas](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/saveas.html)

Someone returns me this error, others give me different ones but no one can save.

```matlab
Error using checkArgsForHandleToPrint
Handle input must be scalar, vector, or cell array of vectors.

Error in checkArgsForHandleToPrint

Error in print>LocalCreatePrintJob (line 101)
handles = checkArgsForHandleToPrint(0, varargin{:});

Error in print (line 38)
[pj, inputargs] = LocalCreatePrintJob(varargin{:});

Error in saveas (line 181)
        print( h, name, ['-d' dev{i}] )
```

Some advice? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

try `savefig`

```
h = figure
surf(peaks)
savefig(h,'PeaksFile.fig')

..

openfig('PeaksFile.fig');
```

or `exportgraphics` . MATLAB version 2020 and above only

```
bar([1 11 7 8 2 2 9 3 6])
f = gcf;

exportgraphics(f,'barchart.png','Resolution',300)
```

or

```
exportgraphics(gcf,'vectorfig.pdf','ContentType','vector')
```